# Labels of USB-drives mounted to Google TV

Tags: android, usb, google-tv

When I plug an USB flash drive to my Logitech Revue, it is mounted into `/mnt/media/usb.C7E3-1E08`.

C7E3-1E08 looks like to be some usb device id, but I want my app to show the label of the USB-drive (like MYFLASH).

GoogleTV knows this label, because in logcat I have this:

```
I/MediaVolume(141): New volume - Label:[FLASH4GB] FsType:vfat UUID:C7E3-1E08
```

Here FLASH4GB is the label of my USB drive. Of course, I can try to parse logcat in my app, but maybe there is some better way to get this label?

Also if I go Home-Notifications, I can see "Synced USB Storage "FLASH4GB"".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no public API for getting the label of volume. There is a chance we will make related API public at some point, but timeline is not decided.

Comment: Have these been made public yet?

Comment: As of yet it seems like the Android auto-mounter still doesn't do this most basic of tasks. It's extremely annoying.